# httpclient5.jat compatible google-http-client-apache-v2 jar is available

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x, google-http-client

httpcient5.jat compatible google-http-client-apache-v2 jar is available

we are trying to migrate httpcomponents.client.jar version 4 to 5 (httpcomponents.client5.jar)
in this case our depended google-http-client-apache-v2 latest 1.43.3 still using the old version on httpcomponents.client.jar(version 4...) is there any alternative.

we try to use ApacheHttpTransport which can added have to use the httpcomponents.client5.jar